# How to set Indentation of block sequences using ruamel-yaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am writing a code using ruamel-yaml to read YAML file, add contents and write back to YAML.

When dumping the YAML, I am not able to set the indentation to top-level mapping

My YAML looks like(This is how the old YAML looks like before editing):

```
Device:
      Name: "ABC"
      Version: "0.2.1"
      Year: "2011"
      Array: [[1,2],
        [3,4],[5,6],
         [7,8]]
```

However,  I want the YAML to look like:

```
Device:
      Name     : "ABC"
      Version  : "0.2.1"
      Year     : "2011"
      Array    : [[1,2],
                 [3,4],[5,6],
                 [7,8]]
```

I want all the quotes to be in the same line and values exactly to the right side of the quotes:

My code:

```
yaml= ruamel.yaml.YAML()

yaml.top_level_colon_align = True

with open('text1.yaml', 'w') as fp:
    round_trip_dump(yaml_content, fp, indent=5, block_seq_indent=3)
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The `yaml` format is wrong in your post.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean ? @jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: I have tested your `yaml` example, it would raise exception when I try to load it.

Comment: Do you mean the code example  ?

Comment: Not the code, it is the `yaml` you post.It seems the `Array` is wrong.

Comment: [["A", "B"],
 ["A", "C"],
 ["A", "D"]]

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA The value for key `Array` are flow style sequences nested in a flow-style sequence, spread over multiple lines. That is perfectly fine YAML. If you don't agree please point to the relevant clause in the YAML specification that states this is not allowed

Comment: @Anthon :(,that's not what I mean,but it will raise exception when I try to load the yaml.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `ruamel.yaml`, it can provide you with aligned colons and values, but only on the top level of the data structure ( `yaml.toplevel_colon_align = True` ). IIRC the same mechanisme cannot easily be applied to nested mappings, as I would not have restricted this to the top level if it could.

Apart from the line width, there is no way to control the multi-line flow-style sequence. During loading **no** track is kept of newlines within the flow-style complex node. This could be done (it is e.g. done in multi-line literal/folded scalars.

If both keeping track of newlines in flow-style nodes as well as nested alignments are implemented, then it is more likely to output aligned elements within the sequence:

```
  .
  .
  Array    : [[1,2],
              [3,4],[5,6]
              [7,8]]
```

Implementing this is a non-trivial effort (as new features, but certainly as subclasses of the current implementation)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. Can we just have something to have all the colons in one line ?